# How to return the derived type from the base type

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a base class, Sport, that has a property will return the proper type of object it should be for a given derived type (for example, Billiards extends Sport, and the property would return the BilliardBall type).

Is there a better way to do this  than having a large if statement in the Sport class (if this object is a Billiards instance then return BilliardBall, else if...)?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're talking about? This seems like it might be a poor design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you talking generics here? And why is Sport knowing about all the sports there are?

You can do something like below, for starters:

```
public interface IBall
{
}
public class BilliardBall : IBall
{
}
public abstract class Sport
{
    protected abstract IBall Ball { get; }

}
public class Billiards : Sport
{
    protected override IBall Ball
    {
        get { return new BilliardBall(); }
    }
}
```